# is there a DB client which supports oracle editions?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

We are using a clever feature or oracle 11gr2 called edition-based redefinitions.

This means each stored proc and view looks different depending on the edition you set in the session.  There are multiple versions of each of these objects.

I'm trying to find a DB client (for browsing data and running SQL) which supports this properly - ie can show me visually the different editions, etc.

DBVisualizer doesn't seem to do this.  Here's an example:

my program code (which explicitly sets an edition) says:
ORA-04063: package body "MATT2.ER_BATCH_SUB_PKG" has errors

But when looking in dbvisualizer to the 'invalid objects' view, I see nothing.

Comment: I would expect Oracle's SQL Developer to support that.

Comment: even SQLPLUS supports editions. My guess is you have to alter your user session to a specific edition and then you will be able to see errors for the code in that edition. I have not played with editions, but this is just a guess.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks yes you're right, it does.